# Dynamic Sumif Formula in Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I want to convert a Sumif Formula in excel to a VBA dynamic code. I want this formula always will be in the last row and could calculate what I need. I did a macro record and tried to insert an integer instead of the number of the row but it's not working.

for example,
this month I have 175 rows, next time i will have maybe 200 or 140, all the rest keeps the same.

Here is my code with the record i made to the formula:

```
Dim ir As Integer

ir = Range("H1", Range("H1").End(xlDown)).Rows.Count
Range("H2").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0).Select

ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
    "=SUMIF(R[-174]C[-5]:R[-1]C[-5],""*total*"",R[-174]C:R[-1]C)"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) You need to incorporate your last row variable into your formula line, taking care to ensure it's outside the quotes;

2) Use Long rather than Integer (more efficient and handles more rows);

3) Work up from the bottom to find the last row (in case you have only 1 row);

4) No need to use Select/ActiveCell.

```
Sub x()

Dim ir As Long

ir = Range("H" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

Range("H" & ir + 1).FormulaR1C1 = "=SUMIF(R[-" & ir & "]C[-5]:R[-1]C[-5],""*total*"",R[-" & ir & "]C:R[-1]C)"

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

R1C1 notation is used in to ways: absolute R1C1 or relative R[-1]C[1]. You can get rid of all this just using absolute notation:

```
Range("H2").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0).FormulaR1C1 = _
    "=SUMIF(R1C[-5]:R[-1]C[-5],""*total*"",R1C:R[-1]C)"
```

Not sure if is from first row (R1), not specified in your code.

Comment: Like it, nice and simple.